# How to save a StyledDocument from textPane into a .doc file?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, doc, styleddocument

I don't know if this is even possible, but what I would like to do is to save a Styled Document (user can change text: bold, underline, italic and 3 sizes of font) in a .doc file - so he could open it later on his own with any other text editor that supports styled text.

I wrote the code below... the editor works, I can apply the styles on the text but when I save, it saves the text just black, with no styles. I can't figure out where is the problem. Maybe the actions don't save. I tried with writer and with buffered writer but it didn't work. I also tried to use HTML editor kit and it didn't work at all - it saved a blank document.

Maybe anyone has an idea how can I save the styles? Appreciate the help :)

```
public class EditFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

JFrame frameEdit = this;
File file; //A file I would like to save to -> fileName.doc
StyledDocument doc;   
HashMap<Object, Action> actions;
StyledEditorKit kit;

public EditFrame() {
    super();
    initComponents();
    JMenu editMenu = createEditMenu();
}

protected JMenu createEditMenu() {
    JMenu menu = editMenu;

    Action action = new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction();
    action.putValue(Action.NAME, "Bold");
    menu.add(action);

    action = new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction();
    action.putValue(Action.NAME, "Italic");
    menu.add(action);

    //...

    return menu;
}

//I'm guessing this doesn't work correctly too (doesn't read styles), but this is another subject :)
public void readFile(File f) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "windows-1250"));
        textPane.read(reader, null);
        textPane.requestFocus();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EditFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

//SAVE METHOD
private void save(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
    try {
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        kit = (StyledEditorKit) textPane.getEditorKit();
        doc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();
        kit.write(out, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EditFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EditFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EditFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                     

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new EditFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`RTFEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html), which supports [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (RTF). Lots of word processors, including MS Word, can work with this format. Stick with [`write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-javax.swing.text.Document-int-int-) to an `OutputStream`, which writes "a format appropriate for this kind of content handler." The other one that uses a `Writer` writes "to the given stream as plain text."

> Why is `StyledEditorKit` not working?

[`StyledEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html) gets its `write()` implementation from [`DefaultEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html), "which treats text as plain text." `StyledEditorKit` stores styled text internally, but it doesn't know about any external format. You have to go to one of the subclasses, `HTMLEditorKit` or `RTFEditorKit`, to get something that override's the default `write()`. The overridden method knows how to transform the internal format to an external format, like RTF.

Comment: Is there really no other way but to use a different (in this case RTF) format? Why is StyledEditorKit not working? I bet I'm just not saving something the right way...

Comment: I think that's the way it's designed. I tried to explain above.

Comment: Catalina Island thank you for the explanation.. I will try with HTML first and let you know if I have any problems.